# How do I continue sending keypress on an application even if it is not on focused using c#?

Tags: keypress

I would like to keep sending numbers from 1-5 in a notepad even if I am opening chrome or other applications.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to post some code showing you've attempted something and it isn't working or tell us what you did to attempt to solve the problem if there is no code. If you don't have anything, start with Google. Lots of tutorials there.

Comment: @HazardousGlitch I already tried using  SetForegroundWindow function, it does not  satisfy on what I want to achieve.